# How to create ID (by) before merging in R?

Tags: r, merge, match, data.table

I have two dataframes `df.o` and `df.m` as defined below. I need to find which observation in `df.o` (dimension table) corresponds which observations in `df.m` (fact table) based on two criteria: 1) `df.o$Var1==df.o$Var1` and `df.o$date1 < df.m$date2 < df.o$date3` such that I get the correct value of `df.o$oID` in `df.m$oID` (the correct value is manually entered in `df.m$CORRECToID`). I need the ID to complete a merge afterwards.

```
df.o <- data.frame(oID=1:4,
                  Var1=c("a","a","b","c"),
                  date3=c(2015,2011,2014,2015),
                  date1=c(2013,2009,2012,2013),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df.m <- data.frame(mID=1:3,
                      Var1=c("a","a","b"),
                      date2=c(2014,2010,2013),
                      oID=NA,
                      CORRECToID=c(1,2,3),
                      points=c(5, 10,15),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I have tried various combinations of like the code below, but without luck:

```
df.m$oID[df.m$date2 < df.o$date3 & df.m$date2 > df.o$date1 & df.o$Var1==df.m$Var1] <- df.o$oID
```

I have also tried experimenting with various combinations of `ifelse`, `which` and `match`, but none seem to do the trick.

The problem I keep encountering is that my replacement was a different number of rows than data and that "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

Comment: Is there a reason why all of the values are characters? Why the date aren't just numbers?

Comment: No reason in particular. Could be dates as well. Just to make it simpler, but if it affects the solution, I ought of course to change it...

Comment: How is `c("2015","2011","2014","2015")` simpler than just `(2015,2011,2014,2015)`?

Comment: You're right - just changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an "*overlap join*", you could try the `data.table::foverlaps` function in order to achieve this.

The idea is simple

1. Create the columns to overlap on (add an additional column to `df.m`)
2. key by these columns
3. run `foverlaps` and select the column you want back

   ```
   library(data.table)
   setkey(setDT(df.m)[, date4 := date2], Var1, date2, date4)
   setkey(setDT(df.o), Var1, date1, date3)
   foverlaps(df.m, df.o)[, names(df.m), with = FALSE]
   #    mID Var1 date2 oID CORRECToID points date4
   # 1:   2    a  2010   2          2     10  2010
   # 2:   1    a  2014   1          1      5  2014
   # 3:   3    b  2013   3          3     15  2013
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this on my original data, but got the following error message: `Error in if (any(x[[xintervals[2L]]] - x[[xintervals[1L]]] < 0L)) stop("All entries in column ",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: You probably have NAs there, remove them and try again. You can use the `na.omit` function that has the `col` argument.

Comment: I did that, but something happens I don't understand: Before doing `na.omit` i did `nrow(df)`, which returned, say 1000. Then I did `sum(is.na(df$x))`, which returned 0 (indicating that I don't have any NA's I suppose). I then did `df <- na.omit(df,cols("x))` and after doing `nrow(df)` I now get a lower number, say 500. Why are there less rows?

Comment: Should be `df <- na.omit(df,col = "x")`, no?

Comment: Yes, `df <- na.omit(df,cols="x")`. I have several columns, so I guess the form I use is `df <- na.omit(df,cols=c("x","y"))`

Comment: I don't know, you need to investigate your data. Something is messed up there.

Comment: Continued working with your solution, and it works fine, thanks again! Just have one small additional question: What is the purpose of the `[, date4 := date2]` part, i.e. why do we need to duplicate date2?

Comment: I've explained it in my first point. You need to create intervals so `foverlaps` will know where is the beginning and the end of each interval. I agree it doesn't make much sense, but this is the current design. This was brought up already many times and the devs trying to improve this.